# Returning whether or not a number is prime as a Boolean in Python

Tags: python, boolean, primes

For context, I am trying to solve [Project Euler problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) using Python:

> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

As a first step to this, I am trying to write a function that returns whether or not a number is prime as a Boolean. I made a first attempt, and checked out how this has been written previously. I have ended up with the following code:

```
def isprime(x):
    limit = x**0.5
    i = 2

    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        while i <= limit:
            if x%i == 0:          
                return False
                i = i + 1       
            else:
                return True
```

For some reason, the code above does not work perfectly. For example, `isprime(99)` would return True.

Please, can someone help me understand why this isn't working? I am trying to avoid just copying and pasting someone else's code, as I want to understand exactly what is going on here.

To me, it looks like the issue is with the final `else` statement. I say this because the logic reads "in the event that `x%i == 0`, this number is not prime" but it doesn't explicitly say what to do in the event that no `x%i` iterations `== 0`.

Any help on this would be appreciated! I'm not necessarily looking for the cleanest, neatest way of doing this, but more just trying to first make this code work.

Comment: The line `i = i + 1 ` is never reached.

Comment: `return` ends function at once and code after `return` is never executed - `i = i + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to show an alternative, what you could do is checking from number 2 to your number if the operation `(x % i)` is equal to zero. If it never happend, it will be a prime.

```py
def isprime(x):
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,x):
       if (x % i) == 0:
           return False
   else:
       return True

print(isprime(99))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
def isprime(x):
    limit = x**0.5
    i = 2
    if x <= 2:
        return False

    while i <= limit:
        if x%i == 0:          
            return False      
        i = i + 1
    return True
```

I've changed many things. have this point in your mind that there is no need to `else` clauses when you `return` at the end of `if` block.

Comment: thanks everyone, cleared up some issues regarding indentation and use of else!

Answer (score 1):

you need to tell what happens when `x%i==0` condition not met and the value of `i` remain constant and also need to see when all conditions not met, then it is a prime

```
# your code goes here
def isprime(x):
    limit = x**0.5
    i = 2

    if x < 2:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    else:
        while i <= limit:
            if x%i == 0:         
                return False
            i+=1
    return True
print(isprime(144)) # false
print(isprime(99)) # false
print(isprime(131)) # true
```